# unity & webgl link not recognized issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

hey I am doing a unity basic course from unity itself, in one of its parts, it wants us to work with a microgame and share its WebGL link once we manage to build it

[here is an error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5vKE.png)

here is the link for my edited microgame https://play.unity.com/p/noobshooter/edit

I have tried to add the link multiple times but nothing is happening

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding: https://play.unity.com/p/noobshooter instead?

Comment: can you tell me why this one works, also thanks it works, but why

let me guess, is it because of the edit, as edit is a facility only available to the publisher and not a user

Comment: @Nikhil yeah, the link to the game is the one I showed you, the /edit makes it no longer link to the game directly, is my guess. Would appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: am sorry man, I am new to coding and its field so do not know much, I even did not know you need to accept an answer as well, is their also a need to close this question or something like that

Comment: thanks. No there's no need, as soon as you accept an answer, the question is basically considered closed, but others are still free to add new answers or add new information